# Servlets , JPA - Login issue

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, jpa

I have problem with my login servlet.

```
TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u", User.class);
    List<User> userList = query.getResultList();
    for (User users : userList) {
        if (email.equals(users.getEmail()) && password.equals(users.getPassword())) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginSucces.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
            break;
        }
```

It's work prettey well, when i type correct email and password existing in database, but when I add else :

```
TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u", User.class);
    List<User> userList = query.getResultList();
    for (User users : userList) {
        if (email.equals(users.getEmail()) && password.equals(users.getPassword())) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginSucces.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
            break;
        } else {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>Wrong data</font>");
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
            break;
        }
    }
```

With else it's always shows "Wrong data" anyway i typed correct or incorrect email and password. Where I made mistake?

Comment: Where do You use this code? What first shows when you type wrong data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a design problem, and a logic problem.

Let's start with the latter: you're loading **all** the users from the database and, start with the first one, and either include the error page (if the first user doesn't have the searched credentials), or include the success page (if the first user has the searched credentials).

That's not what you want to do. What you want to do is loop over the users **until** you find the searched one. Then, after the loop, if you have found the user, include the success page once or, if you haven't found him, include the error page.

Now let's continue with the design problem. Imagine you're implementing Facebook for a moment. Would you find it a good strategy to load 1 billion users in memory from the database and loop through all of them, only to find if **one** of them has the entered email and password. That is insane. A database is precisely used to let you search through the data using queries.

You need a query that searches the user based on the entered email, and returns only **one** user (if found), or 0 (if not found):

```
select u from User u where u.email = :email
```

I won't even talk about the third problem you have: a security problem. You should never store the password, in clear-text, of a user in the database. It should be salted randomly and hashed with a strong cryptographic hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks for tips I fixed this by this way:

```
try {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u where u.email = :email", User.class);
        q.setParameter("email", email);
        User userEmail = (User) q.getSingleResult();
        if (email.equals(userEmail.getEmail()) && password.equals(userEmail.getPassword())) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginSucces.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
        } else {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>Wrong password</font>");
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException e) {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font color=red>User dont exists</font>");
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }
```

I'm novice at java